# Initiate panel with drawings

Tags: c#

I am now drawing to a panel some dots to indicate a sort of dotted grid with 1% of margin of total panel width.

This is what I am doing now:

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen my_pen = new Pen(Color.Gray);
        int x,y;
        int k = 1 ,t = 1;
        int onePercentWidth = panel1.Width / 100;

        for (y = onePercentWidth; y < panel1.Height-1; y += onePercentWidth)
        {
            for (x = onePercentWidth; x < panel1.Width-1; x += onePercentWidth) 
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(my_pen, x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

What is bothering me is that when the app starts I can see the dots being drawn on the panel. Even if it is very quick it still bothers me a lot.

Is it possible to draw the dots on the panel and load it directly drawn?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a bitmap and draw it instead.

But before you do that: `DrawEllipse` is a little expensive. Use `DrawLine` with a `Pen` that has a dotted linestyle instead:

```
int onePercentWidth = panel1.ClientSize.Width / 100;

using (Pen my_pen = new Pen(Color.Gray, 1f))
{
  my_pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Custom;
  my_pen.DashPattern = new float[] { 1F,  onePercentWidth -1 };
  for (int y = onePercentWidth; y < panel1.ClientSize.Height - 1; y += onePercentWidth)
       e.Graphics.DrawLine(my_pen, 0, y, panel1.ClientSize.Width, y);
}
```

Note that I am using `using` so I don't leak the `Pen` and `ClientSize` so I use only the inner width. Also note the exaplanation about the custom `DashPattern` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.pen.dashpattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Okay I do now realize that I was complaining about something caused  by my terrible programming. Thanks for the help.. it works exactly as I wanted even though I think I need to still understand how it can draw all over the panel and not only on one line. I will check clientsize and using to understand.

Comment: Please see the tiny correction (`onePercentWidth -1 };`). - It draws a number of lines all over the Panel, each with a dotted style which is perfectly fitting the lines' spacing. (I am saving one pair of braces after the for loop; not really a recommended coding style..) - But yes, Drawing has many tricks, pitfalls and wonders all over the place.. Have fun learning it!